# Not working HTTPS Node.js Server on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, configure

[My site](http://www.newbieworkco.com/) is not working on HTTPS. Now it is working good on HTTP.

We added below code in `server.js` file, but we have no idea how to get `private-key.pem` and `scr.pem` files.

```js
key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt')
```

Can someone tell me what I need to fix to enable HTTPS?

Comment: are you using ELB (Elastic load balancing)?

Comment: `we do not have idea how to get private-key.pem and scr.pem files.` Have you bought a ssl certificate?

Answer (score 0):

To get those files you have 2 options:

1. Generate private key and certificate on your machine using some tool like openssl, keygen, etc.
2. Purchase it online or some sites gives it away free for testing.

After you get those files, put the correct path and filename.